# Probability question - Assume non-exponential and use discrete numbers

Tags: probability

1. A new equipment purchased by Toyata motors has an annual hazard rate of 2%. (Note: do not use an exponential distribution)

What is the probability that the equipment will fail before year 100?

Why is this $1-0.98^{99}$ and not $1-0.98^{100}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important word here is "before" so you do not count the year 100.

$P($will fail before year 100$)$ = $1-P($ Does not fail in year $1$ to $99.)$ = $1-(1-0.02)^{99}= 1-0.98^{99}$

(Assuming that the failure in each year is independent of its life time. I am not quite sure what your "Note" is meant to imply.)

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense. The note was there by the proff to tell us not to use exponential distirbution for this question.